# HTML страницу перенести в Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, документация

Всем привет!

Для начала немного предистории и описание конечной цели, возможно кто нибудь подскажет лучше идею!

Итак, решили создать сайт саппорта на сабдомене на движке Wordpress, имеется документация которая генерируется с помощью ASCII Doctor в HTML, и автоматически заливается на сервер. На этом же сайте есть потребность делать информативные лендинги, предполагается текучка контента, поэтому решили в пользу CMS, что бы человек с минимальными навыками мог взаимодействовать и создавать страницы и контент!

А теперь к ПРОБЛЕМЕ:
сложность в том что бы сгенерированные страницы документации от ASCII Doc залить как отдельные страницу Wordpress сохранив header и footer шаблона, тут более не менее понятно, но так же сохранить стили параметры страниц документации, кто не в курсе, они выглядят как полноценная страница со стилями через style в хедере.

Можно было бы закрыть глаза и кинуть их просто в корень Wordpress, но требуется так же функционирующий поиск, который по этим страницам тоже будет искать, поиски по типу Google модулей выглядят не привлекательно, с точки зрения дизайна.

Буду рад и благодарен за ваши советы и идеи, может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобными задачами!

Comment: саппорт какой то ! не ужели в русском языке нету слова которое 100% подходит ? надо или писать по английскому или писать по русскому ...хэдер - шапка , саппорт - поддержка ...

Comment: спасибо, вы очень помогли! в следующий раз напишу даже в заголовке "Страницу написанную на языкe гипертекстовой разметки перенести в СловоПрессы"